# Fullcalendar - external event on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a problem with fullcalendar script. I cant get attributes of clicked divs.
I need to get id attribute of an external event

this is the div

```
<div id="1303" class="fc-event"  data-color="#9900cc">
<span class="mr-1 badge bg-orange" style="width: 5%; padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">-26</span>Some text
</div>
```

this is the code on click

```
$('#external-events').on('click', '.fc-event', () => {
    const element = $(this);
    console.log(Object.keys(element));
    console.log(Object.values(element));
    console.log(Object.entries(element));
})
```

and this is the result

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuEEy.jpg)

How can i get attributes of these divs(there are more that 1)? Where is my mistake? if i do `element.attr('id')` i get 'undefined'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `element.attr("id")`

Comment: Yes i had but nothing...

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet?

Comment: @DmytroV It's not working because you use arrow function. `this` is not working with arrow functions. Either change `() =>` to `function()`, or add `(e) =>` and use `$(e.target)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen weird...I used a similar technique and it worked

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen but your example work perfectly... thank you very much!

Comment: Just an observation - this seems to have nothing to do with fullCalendar directly, all the problem you're having is about jQuery usage, and HTML elements which are outside the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson, now i know it, thank you. I just thought i could not do my operation cause there are, idk how, not editable.